# Pass to callback un updated value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, begininvoke, iasyncresult

with *IAsyncResult* pattern I'm implementing an asynchornous operation.

The signature of the beginning of my invocation is:

```
object[] data = new object[] {field1,field2};

AsyncSendMessageToSystem caller = SendMessageToSystem;
caller.BeginInvoke(field1,field2,field3, new AsyncCallback(callbackMethod),data);
```

When the **callbackMethod** is invoked, it has as input the **data** object. 
The **field1** var is intended to be modified inside **SendMessageToSystem**, but **callbackMethod** will receive original value, and no the updated one.

How could I pass to callback the updated value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify if the callback method is receiving the original value? The way this works is that your callback method gets the reference to the object `data`, since `object[]` is a reference type. You need to make sure the modification to `field1` happens before the callback is called.